# How to write complete "sed"command

Tags: sed, openshift, kubernetes-secrets

I tried sed command at Mac's terminal but it is showing ">" and couldn't execute the command.

```
username$ oc get secret all-icr-io -n default -o yaml | sed 's/default/my-project/g’ | oc create -n my-project -f -
>
```

I got this command from
[here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openshift?topic=openshift-registry#copy_imagePullSecret)
(③Copy the all-icr-io image pull secret from the default project to the project of your choice. The new image pull secrets are named <project_name>-icr--io.)

What I am trying to do is to copy OpenShift secret to from one namespace to another.
"my-project" is existing project.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the "smart quotes", use the ASCII ones only. The shell thinks the quoted string hasn't been closed.

```
's/default/my-project/g’
                       ~
```

Comment: It worked well by changing as you told me .Thank you very much.